# Database output prevent images

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

Is there a way to prevent the output of img-elements out of a database-table?

In my database is some HTML-Code stored:

Table: test_table
Field: code

```
<p>This is simple test!</p><img src="files/test.img">
```

Now I'm outputting the database-content:

```
$code = $db->getValue('code');

<?php echo $code ?>
```

The complete content of the `code` field is outputted. I would like to prevent the output of the `<img>`-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a it in two ways. First as other guys suggest [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) or second using [strip_tags()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) with `allowable_tags` parameter where you can define tags which are allowed. Then you are safe if your output contain other tags which you do not want to echo.

Example from documentation:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```

The above example will output:

```
Test paragraph. Other text
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```

Comment: ```strip_tags()``` is the way to go here. It's way safer than ```preg_match()```. Never parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: Works fine! Thank you, Tomasz!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using css.

```
<div id="content">
$code = $db->getValue('code');

<?php echo $code ?>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content img{display:none;}
```

OR

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
   $('#content img').remove();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You may need to use `preg_replace` by using this , it will replace all the `<img>` with `space` from string.

> if you want to replace with any other thing , modify **`$replaceWith`**.

```
 $content = '<p>This is simple test!</p><img src="files/test.img"><img src="files/test.img">';
    $replaceWith = " "; 
    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", $replaceWith, $content); 
    echo $content;
```

[**Example Demo**](https://ideone.com/9fsQDR)

**Usage with your code:**

```
$code = $db->getValue('code');
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $code); 
echo $content;
```

Comment: Here's your reason: https://3v4l.org/gS9MX - Regular expressions should never be used to parse HTML.